# verification of a method call is failing in unit test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

**My test class:**

```
 @Before
  public void init() {
    arg2= mock(Dispatcher.class);  
    target = new FileHandlerImpl(Dispatcher, service , channel, scope);
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldVerifyCalls() throws Exception {
    final String arg1 = "Some arg 1";
    final String arg3 = "Some arg 3";
    final String arg4 = "Some arg 4";
    target.handleMessage(message, endpointSession);  
    verify(arg2).send(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4); //here is error
}
```

***Error Log:***

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
Dispatcher.send(
    "179fb6c5-9e47-41cc-9903-d0df5a317f55",
    Mock for Dispatcher, hashCode: 992040402,
    null,
    null
);
-> at com.TestApp.FileHandlerTest.shouldVerifyCalls(FileHandlerTest.java:77)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
Dispatcher.send(
    "d6723004-45aa-4958-8a8e-595a01056c82",
    Dispatcher{id=100, serial='null', sentTime=1, priority=99},
    null,
    null
);
```

Comment: What is your question? Mockito's error is exactly telling you what is going on.

Comment: I know about mockito's error that the `arguments are different`. But I just want to check if the `send` method is called once or not regardless of arguments.

Comment: The method `send` was called. Otherwise Mockito would have said something like `Wanted but not invoked`. You could create a simple example and watch its behavior.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula - Can you please provide some simple example to ensure that method is invoked without a test failure?

Comment: Oh, now I understand your question. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Mockito's `Matchers` to achieve what you want. I believe this example will clarify the concept:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

...

List<String> mockedList = mock(List.class);
mockedList.add("test");

// this won't fail the test because the parameters match
verify(mockedList).add("test");

// this will fail the test because Mockito verifies the parameters and they don't match
verify(mockedList).add("other string");

// on the other hand, if you don't care about the parameters, you can use Matchers
verify(mockedList).add(anyString());
// or more generically
verify(mockedList).add(any(String.class));
```

If you want to make sure the method was called only once, you could also use:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
...
verify(mockedList, times(1)).add(anyString());
```

Comment: But one of my method argument is not `string type` so `anyString()` will not be accepted as its argument. It is of type `Dispatcher` where `Dispatcher` is class. How to pass it as a argument ?

Comment: That's why I also presented the generic way to do that. In your case, it would be something like: `verify(yourMock).send(any(Dispatcher.class))`

Comment: There is no matcher with the name `any`. I am getting compile time error when I use it. In which version was it introduced ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't imported that. Let me check.